# How do I write a function that takes a string, codes it in number and return the number as a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, numbers

I tried to write a function that takes in a string, and prints the coded text, with a' as 1, 'b' as 2, ..., 'z' as 26. The output should be a string, with letters separated by ".". For example, encode("Hello!") should print out "8.5.12.12.15.999". Here is my code, but it does not work and I don't know why. Nothing is printed at the end when I run the code.

```
def encode(text = input("Enter a text below please: ")):
    tx = ""
    text = text.lower()
    text = "".join(text.split())
    for x in range(0,len(text)):
        conv_char = ord(text[x]) - 96
        if conv_char > 0 and conv_char <= 26:
            tx += str(conv_char) + "."
            return(tx)
        print(tx)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function and return the full encoding.

```
def encode(text = input("Enter a text below please: ")):
    tx = ""
    text = text.lower()
    text = "".join(text.split())
    for x in range(0,len(text)):
        conv_char = ord(text[x]) - 96
        if conv_char > 0 and conv_char <= 26:
            tx += str(conv_char) + "."
        elif text[x] in [chr(c) for c in range(33,48)]:
            tx += '999.'
    return(tx)
#    print(tx)
        
print(encode())
```

Output

```
Enter a text below please: hello!
8.5.12.12.15.999.
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it, and it works. But, how do I modify the code so that punctuations are coded 999?